# Calling image and descriptions with using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, mobile

my problem is this, I want to call images and descriptions but I have more than 200 images and I don't know how to do it. I already call images but how can I add the description of these images and how can I call descriptions? I know these codes are very long but I still want to show it because for you to understand better.

Summary: I want to call different description for each picture.

This HomePage at a cross section

```
slide('World of Classics', [
                'peter pan in kensington gardens.jpg',
                'peter pan.jpg',
                'odysey.jpg',
                'sherlock holmes.jpg',
                'the idiot.jpg',
                'anna karenina.jpg',
                'Around the World in 80 Days.jpg',
                'art of war.jpg',
                'robinson crouse.jpg',
                'Gullivers travel.jpg',
              ]),
              slide('Full of Love Novels', [
                'aski memnu.jpg',
                'ruh adam.jpg',
                'mor salkimli ev.jpg',
                'ask batagi.jpg',
                'aydakı kadın.jpg',
                'emma.jpg',
                'kurk mantolu madonna.jpg',
                'Love and Mr Lewisham.jpg',
                'madame bovary.jpg',
                'simdi sevisme vakti.jpg',
                // orther images
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget slide(String info, List<String> imageList) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        screenWidth * 0.05,
        screenHeight * 0.02,
        screenWidth * 0.05,
        0.0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            info,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Container(
            height: screenHeight * 0.2,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: imageList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            DetailsPage(imageName: imageList[index]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.20, // box lenght
                    height: screenHeight * 0.1,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/pics/${imageList[index]}'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

ThisDetailsPage at a cross section

```
class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageName;

  const DetailsPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailsPage> createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  late double screenWidth;
  late double screenHeight;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1.0),
                Color.fromRGBO(69, 60, 60, 1.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: screenHeight * 0.04,
                    left: screenWidth * 0.05,
                    right: screenWidth * 0.03),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      iconSize: screenWidth * 0.06,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => HomePage()));
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: screenWidth, // Image size settings
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/pics/${widget.imageName}', // here is images
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  'data', // here is descriptions
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: screenWidth * 0.1 / 3, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
```

I want to make the image descriptions pop up with Flutter but I can't do it, I tried map and list but it didn't work.

Comment: I mean to call up the pics and descriptions from another file. i.e. the pics will appear on another page when clicked and each pic will have a description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show a different description for each image on the HomePage page. For this, you will need to somehow manage the descriptions corresponding to the images in the imageList parameter in the slide widget.

Below is an example of code that will perform this function in the slide widget of the HomePage class. The descriptions are kept in a dictionary based on the imageList list. This dictionary takes the image names as keys and stores the descriptions as values. It is then displayed in DetailsPage using these descriptions in DetailsPage.

Possible Problems : if you get such a warning 'The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.'

Solution:The reason for this error is that DetailsPage's imageName and description parameters are of type String, but where these parameters are called they are of type String? The String? type is a "nullable" type, meaning that it can be null if no value is assigned. However, the String type cannot be null.

To fix this error, you need to use String instead of String? in the constructor of DetailsPage and in HomePage. You can follow these steps to do this:

Use String instead of String? in DetailsPage's constructor and where it is called.
In HomePage, when calling DetailsPage in the slide widget, give String type values to imageName and description parameters.

```
description: imageDescriptions[imageList[index]] ?? "", // Null check added here
```